# Mysql group_concat split by count

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

Is it possible to perform a group_concat in mysql and have some sort of group limit? thus allowing the group to be split over a number of result rows?

e.g.

if I have a table called num like so:

```
    val
    ---
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    ...
```

and I use the statement `select group_concat(val) from num`

I get the result

```
1,2,3,4,5,...
```

What I want to do is set a group limit of 2 and get the result

```
1,2
3,4
5,...
```

Now the use case I have is hundreds of thousands of values that I want to select as neat groups of about 500.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a user variable to create a row number, then group by dividing the row numbers by the group size.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(val) AS vals
FROM (SELECT val, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum
      FROM (SELECT val FROM nums ORDER BY val) AS vals
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := -1) AS vars) AS temp
GROUP BY FLOOR(rownum/500)
```

Comment: It does group them, but not by a standard amount, here are two examples of groupings: vals
group A : 18,21,35,182,234,242,252,264,276,296,392,448,464
group B: 592,676,733,889,912,952,961

Comment: It should group all the numbers from `1` to `500` together, then all the numbers from `501` to `1000`, and so on.

Comment: I've come up with a better solution using a user variable for the group numbering.

Comment: That's lovely! now do it for varchars :)